# What wait can I use to allow the table to update with the correct fleet?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, action, wait

Running selenium and c# to ensure a particular fleet is in the table.  For some reason when I build my script, generates a fleetname and it cannot find it? I get the error.

```
 NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Fleet1021135336101123']"} (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
```

My code is below ads the filterFleetNameFind is pls note the newFleetName is Fleet1021135336101123:

```
//a[text()='Fleet1021135336101123']
```

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(driver => !_fleetRep.filterFleetNameFind(newFleetName).Displayed);
```

Its not picking up the newFleetName

Comment: can you add the html source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Xpath("//a[text()='Fleet1021135336101123']")));
```

kindly check of the text **Fleet1021135336101123** is static and not changing otherwise it won't work